# access value selected from selectoptionlist from visualforce to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

how to access value selected from selectoptionlist from visualforce to controller?
my vf page is below:

```
  <apex:selectList value="{!selectoptions}" size="1">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountCustomer}">
     </apex:selectOptions>
   </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: meera ... is this issue resolved? if yes please accept  the answer so user can identify tis question is resolved

Answer (score 2):

So for selectlist

take a string variable to store the picklist value(for ex. `strSelectVal`) and
create a list of string for picklist values ex. listString

Now you code will be like this

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!strSelectVal}" size="1">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!listString}">
     </apex:selectOptions>
   </apex:selectList>
```

When you select any value and when you call any controller method and check the `strSelectVal` value. it will be your selected picklist value

Comment: hi Ratan, i have intiatialized selectoptions as string.                                             public class Accountname{
public string selectoptions{get;set;}                                                        public list <Account> querycresult{get;set;}                                                         public List<selectoption> getAccountname(){
   querycresult = [select id,name from Account];
for(Account acclist: querycresult){
option.add(new SelectOption(acclist.id,acclist.name));}                           return option;}}

Comment: @jijjkjs check `selectoptions` values in debug logs you will get the values in controller side

Comment: hi ratan,                                                                                                              its showing null.

Comment: @jijjkjs how you are calling method in controller and checking ? Can you provide me your complete sample code

Comment: hi ratan,                                                                                                             its working after adding <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" />

Comment: @jijjkjs great..